# Regex incl new zipcodes

Tags: regex

We have a regex that will handle and validate
danish zipcodes: xxxx
norwegian zipcodes: Nxxxx (inhouse custom pattern)
swedish zipcodes: Sxxxxx (inhouse custom pattern)
greenland zipcodes: Gxxxx (inhouse custom pattern)
iceland zipcodes: xxx

Well you get the idea.

Now I need to incl Faroe island zipcodes on the pattern of FO-xxx

What I have sofar.

```
^(\D[0-9]{2,6}\s\D{3,})|([0-9]{3,6}\s\D{3,})$
```

I've edited the {2,6} from {2,5}, and {3,} from {2,}.

Thank you very much

Comment: Currently, your match result includes a word with at least 3 letters (or more precisely: three non-digits) after the ZIP number. Is that intended?

Comment: @NaveedS: yes, digit.

Comment: @Matthias: that sounds a bit odd, cos the current regex validates the current pattern. 0-1 character + 3-5 digits. You say it is the other way round digits + non-digits.

Comment: @DoStuffZ: Well, it maches the digits, but it needs a whitespace and at least 3 non-digits **after** the actual ZIP.

Comment: @Matthias: Ahh yes now I catch up, those last non-digits become the city which the number cover. 2500 Valby, being the zipcode for the town of Valby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think   `^[NG]?\d{4}|S\d{5}|(FO-)?\d{3}$` would suffice.

This allows any of the following:

- an optional N or G followed by 4 mandatory digits (matches Danish, Norwegian and Greenland)
- an S followed by 5 digits (matches Swedish)
- an optional part of FO- followed by 3 mandatory digits (matches Iceland and Faroe islands)

Your regex `^(\D[0-9]{2,6}\s\D{3,})|([0-9]{3,6}\s\D{3,})$` matches a pattern like this : **a non-digit followed by 2-6 digits followed by a space followed by 3 or more non-digits** or **3-6 digits followed by a space followed by 3 or more non-digits**. This doesn't seem to fulfill your requirement (as stated).

Comment: Looks promising - when I try it on "FO-100 Test-FO100" (yes I created a test zip for the town of Test-FO100), it fails. After I edited in this bit: \s\D{3,} - I am guessing at space + 3 or more non-digits.

Comment: @DoStuffZ then do it with the anchors removed like `[NG]?\d{4}|S\d{5}|(FO-)?\d{3}`. the anchors indicate beginning and end.

Comment: Thank you so much. I swear regex is something the devil invented to do my head in on a good day.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make a simple regex for each zip code, then join them together into one regex programmatically.  This will perform a more accurate check than your existing regex.  It will also be less error prone and much easier to maintain.  Plus, it gives you the ability to do extra things like match a particular country's zip code if you need that in the future.  Here is an example of how I would code it in Perl:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %codes = (
    'Danish' => '\d{4}',
    'Norwegian' => 'N\d{4}',
    'Faroese' => 'FO-\d{3}'
);

my $zip_regex = '^' . join('|', values %codes) . '$';

if ($some_var =~ /$zip_regex/)
{
    print "$some_var is a zip code";
}
```

The approach should be usable in any language.

Comment: Only problem is - it needs to be part of a <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression= >

Comment: @DoStuffZ, this approach would work fine in ASP.  It is simply creating the regex string from a list of string values, which you could do in any language.  I don't use ASP myself, though, so I can't help with specifics.